# REST full API composite key vs primary key

Tags: rest, http

What is the best practice for REST full APIs when I have a primary ID for entity but at the same time this entity can be identified by composite key?

This can be done like this

- `HTTP GET /entity/333` - DB primary key
- `HTTP GET
  /entity/CODE1/to/CODE2/with/CODE3` - this is example how URL for
  composite key could look like

Answer (score 0):

REST doesn't care what spellings you use for your URI; we really only care that the spelling you choose is consistent with the restrictions described in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

If you have two different identifiers, then as far as REST clients are concerned you have two different resources -- the representations returned to the client will be cached under different keys, invalidating one resource will not affect the other in any way.

It is perfectly reasonable two have two (or more) resources that share the same representations.

You can also have the requests for one resource redirected to another.

Part of the point of the hypermedia constraint in REST is that the server(s) control the URI space, so you can freely change them without breaking clients (restriction: breaking the bookmark URI will make a mess).  URL shorteners work.

When designing path segments, it is often useful to keep in mind how [relative-resolution](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2) works, so that your representations can reference other resources relative to a base url, rather than locking into a particular hierarchy.